# Why do I get "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." error?

Tags: swift, parsing

I am making a request to download some data from a parse server that I set up (in this case text) and I get the following error message

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})
```

here is my request code

```
var query1 = PFQuery(className: spotdetail)

            query1.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("AlKeGL1d75", block: { (object, error) in

                if error != nil {

                    print(error)

                } else {

                   print(object?.objectForKey("name"))

                }

            })
```

not that whet I `print(aboutSpot.objectId)` I do get the object ID

What could this be coming from, how could I solve this issue ?

thanks !

Comment: The error message simply means that the JSON is no (valid) JSON.

Comment: does this mean my code is wrong or is it coming from the server itself ? @vadian

Comment: The error doesn't occur in the code you've posted. It occurs while deserializing the JSON string via the `NSJSONSerialization` class. The (most likely) reason is that the received string from the server is no JSON or has a wrong format.

Comment: try pasting your json response into jsonlint.com to check it is valid